# Confusing Build log in TeamCity in case of parallel tests

Tags: java, multithreading, selenium, teamcity, selenium-grid2

I'm using Java, Gradle, TestNG, Selenium Hub and Node on Localhost and trying to run 5 tests in parallel, the following is a sample code.

This is Base class:

```
package tests.temp;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;

public class TestBase
{

protected ThreadLocal<RemoteWebDriver> threadDriver = null;

@BeforeMethod
public void setUp() throws MalformedURLException {

    threadDriver = new ThreadLocal<RemoteWebDriver>();
    DesiredCapabilities dc = new DesiredCapabilities();
    FirefoxProfile fp = new FirefoxProfile();
    dc.setCapability(FirefoxDriver.PROFILE, fp);
    dc.setBrowserName(DesiredCapabilities.firefox().getBrowserName());
    threadDriver.set(new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"), dc));
}

public WebDriver getDriver() {
    return threadDriver.get();
}

@AfterMethod
public void closeBrowser() {
    getDriver().quit();

}

}
```

Here is an example of 1 Test. Other Tests are the same except names and numbers:

```
package tests.temp;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class Test01 extends TestBase
{

@Test
public void testLink()throws Exception
{

    getDriver().get("http://www.yandex.ru");
    WebElement textBox = getDriver().findElement(By.name("text"));
    textBox.sendKeys("First test");
    System.out.println("First test thread-count=\"1\"");

}

}
```

An XML-file with Suite, with all this 5 Tests:

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Parallel test runs" parallel="tests" thread-count="1">

<test name="Test_01">
    <classes>
        <class name="tests.temp.Test01" ></class>
    </classes>
</test>

 ...

<test name="Test_05">
    <classes>
        <class name="tests.temp.Test05" ></class>
    </classes>
</test>

</suite>
```

And the last - XML-file with Suite runner:

```
<suite name="Parallel Test Suite">
<suite-files>
    <suite-file path="./testRunner.xml" />
</suite-files>
</suite>
```

The trouble is: in case I use thread-count="1" Build log in TeamCity looks fine, but Tests runs sequentially of course.
[TeamCity thread = 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bu5Pm.png)

If thread-count="2" or any other value - Build log looks confusing and Tests counter value is not correct. But in IDEA - everything is cool and correct!
[TeamCity thread = 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dFUrv.png)

Does anyone know how to solve this trouble??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you report tests running in parallel, you should assign them [flowId](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Build+Script+Interaction+with+TeamCity#BuildScriptInteractionwithTeamCity-MessageFlowId) so that TeamCity understood which message belongs to which test. Without flowId not only build log, but also tests statistics will be incorrect. Without flowId TeamCity can also mistakenly mark test as failed even if this failure was reported by other test.
As to displaying parallel tests properly in build log, see the request in TeamCity tracker: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-8249. Please vote for it.

Comment: Alina, thanks! I voted. And it looks like Gradle has the same trouble in logs http://prntscr.com/bhsnla

Comment: If this answered your question, please accept it as the answer so that the question doesn't stay open. Thanks.